# How do I add confirm function to links in jQuery so that the dialog always appears?

Tags: jquery, onclick, confirm

I have a HTML table that displays rows of records and has a column on the end with a delete link. Each delete link has a class of confirm-delete. I need to have a confirm dialog popup on click and as it is used in multiple pages, have created a confirm function in an external JS file.

I have added the function call to the link's click using jQuery [code at bottom of post] and it works fine until the dialog has been confirmed once [user has clicked OK]. Then the function is no longer called.

I think I am missing something pretty simple though as I don't use JS/jQuery much I may have a gap in my knowledge. Why does it work fine until the first OK? It appears to be storing a reference to the result and reusing it rather than a unique one for each link.

Here's the code when used on the Notes page:

```
$(function() {
        // Add Confirmation dialogs for all Deletes
        $("a.confirm-delete").click(function(event) {
            return fConfirmDelete('Note');
        });
});
```

And the fConfirmDelete function

```
function fConfirmDelete( deleteObj ) {
    return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this ' + deleteObj + '?');
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of function fConfirmDelete()?

Comment: Edited the question to include fConfirmDelete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the user clicks OK the first time, do you somehow reload the table dynamically? If so, it could be that the event isn't bound to the re-loaded table. Try a [live event handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead:

#### jQuery 1.7+

```
$(function() {
        // Add Confirmation dialogs for all Deletes
        $(document).on('click', 'a.confirm-delete', function(event) {
            return fConfirmDelete('Note');
        });
});
```

#### jQuery 1.3-1.8:

```
$(function() {
        // Add Confirmation dialogs for all Deletes
        $("a.confirm-delete").live('click', function(event) {
            return fConfirmDelete('Note');
        });
});
```

In your original code, `$("a.confirm-delete").click(...)` will only bind the event to `a.confirm-delete` objects *already in the DOM*. If you add a new `a.confirm-delete` element later, the event is not bound to it. By using jQuery's live event handler, the event will be bound to any `a.confirm-delete` elements that currently exist or any that get created dynamically.

Comment: Ah-ha! A lightbulb went off over my head as I read your first sentence, and then your code gave me the solution too. Perfect answer!

Comment: `live()` is deprecated use `on()` instead

Comment: @AndyLobel thanks, i did not know they had deprecated `.live`. Updated the example to use the new syntax.

Answer (score 3):

@bradenkeith is probably correct with his answer but you might want to leverage jQuery a little more and do a jQuery dialog as well.

```
$("a.confirm-delete").click(function(event) {
      var message = fConfirmDelete(deleteObj);
      var $dialog = $j('<div></div>')
                    .html(message)
                    .dialog({
                     autoOpen: true,
                     bgiframe: true,
                     buttons: {
                       'Dismiss': function() { $j(this).dialog('close');}
                       'Delete': function() { //Do delete things }
                     }
                     modal: true
                     // other parameters here 
                    });

  });
```

Something like that might be easier to read and maintain in my opinion.

Just an option. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
      // Add Confirmation dialogs for all Deletes
      $("a.confirm-delete").click(function(event) {
          if(fConfirmDelete('Note')){
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }
      }); 
});
```

Comment: how is this any different from what he has?

Comment: Kip, fConfirmDelete will either return True or False based on the user clicking OK or Cancel. Should the function return true, return true (continuing the submission of the action) will fire. Should they click cancel, return false will block the original action of a.confirm-delete

Comment: yeah, but how is `if(x) return true; else return false;` any different from `return x;` ?

Comment: I believe I may have misunderstood the question. However, this structure will give him more leverage with the users' response so it may not be all that bad that it was offered.